# calculating distance in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

I want to get the distance from my current location to destination. I do have the Longitude and latitude of the destination in my JSON file. How can I get the longitude and latitude of my current location so that I can calculate the distance between two points? I tried the code below in my android emulator, but I keep getting the time out issues.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

I just want to get the distance from the current location to destination in miles. How can I achieve that?  Below is the screen along with the error [image]that I am getting :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: Please rename the question to somthing like location timeout issue when using `react native geolocation`. So that i should reach to more and more people who are fasing this issue

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced the same issue, What I found is, If you execute tests "**inside your office**" using physical device, the GPS locator can be disturbed by external things like walls, or by the simple reason that you are trying to do this operation "indoor" and, generally, this should be executed outdoor.

My suggestion is: try geolocation using **enableHighAccuracy** set to `true`, if this fail with **location request timed out** error (in the office this can fail), retry with `false`, this should work, in my case it did.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I can calculate the distance, thats the easy part. I need the longitude and latitude of the current location. How can I do that?

Comment: Than you should have given question title like, Not getting curent position using geolocation API. Anyway have you tried increasing the timeout?

Comment: Yes, I tried increasing the timeout. Still the same issue

Comment: @user54967 I have updated the answer. I my case, above solution worked and I hope it will work for you too. Thanks

Comment: I put enableHighAccuracy =false. I pasted my updated code above. This is only happening in android.apple computer is fine,

Comment: It's working for me with enableHighAccuracy set to false but its not giving accurate position. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I still did not find any solution. Its working on mac computer, but not on PC

Comment: Okay, it seems to be a real issue. Actually I am also kinda stuck in this.

Comment: Let me know if you find the solution

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer as its the best solution to the problem. As a solution to the `location timeout issue` i am using [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) and it works like a charm.

This library has been created to fix the location timeout issue on android with the react-native's current implementation of `Geolocation API`. This library tries to solve the issue by using Google Play Service's new `FusedLocationProviderClient API`, which Google strongly recommends over android's default framework location API.